# Creating community user with flows

Tags: visual-flows

I am creating community user with a flow. I am passing all the required fields, but running the flow results in error.

my error is :
Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: PORTAL_NO_ACCESS: no access to portal. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable community in your org. And then check again.